# How can I debug a python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdb, pdb

I am quite new to python and trying to understand how can I troubleshoot an issue in a python application which is using python api to call functions in a C library. Looks like respective C  function is not able to process things as expected. I am not sure how can i troubleshot the same without adding more printfs and rebuilding the whole library.

In C, we have GDB and STRACE which are helpful in understanding trace of functions and adding breakpoints to understand the values in the respective variables. Is there anything equivalent to do similar stuff in python ?

Comment: If the problem is inside the C library, then I don't understand how Python debugging will help...

Comment: Well I am not sure if the problem is inside the c library or not .. since python api is calling the same I wanted to know by putting a breakpoint on shared C library to check the flow.

Comment: So, did you try putting a breakpoint in the C library?

Comment: Thats the question i had ... In order to put breakpoint in C library in this case I need to run python application which is using it in a debugger right ? For e.g. if I take GDB how can i do the same with a python application

Comment: Start your debugging with something very simple: Make a standalone python script that calls the python api, and check if you get the correct results back.